# How to solve zsh command not found error graphql-faker

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to use graphql-faker package in my nextjs project. As stated in the documentation `https://github.com/graphql-kit/graphql-faker` i run

`npm install -g graphql-faker` the `graphql-faker --open` but it throws `zsh: command not found: graphql-faker`

I tried a lot of things:

`export PATH=$PATH:$(npm bin -g)`

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local`

and extc.. But didn't work. How can i solve this?

Comment: There is no need to guess, just figure out the absolute path to `graphql-faker` and add it to `PATH`.